# Summation under a given assumption (returning piecewise function)

Tags: sympy

I am looking to evaluate the sum an infinite geometric series in SymPy, and want to use the fact that I know the sum has to converge. (Similar to this post: [How to Sum with conditions on Sympy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085452/how-to-sum-with-conditions-on-sympy))

My code:

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy import oo
from sympy.assumptions import assuming, Q
from sympy.assumptions.assume import global_assumptions

x,k = sp.symbols('x k')

#global_assumptions.add(Q.is_true(sp.Abs(x)<1))

with assuming(Q.is_true(sp.Abs(x)<1)):

    y = sp.Sum(x**k,(k,0,oo)).doit()
    print y
```

The result is:

```
Piecewise((1/(-x + 1), Abs(x) < 1), (Sum(x**k, (k, 0, oo)), True))
```

So it seems the assumption that abs(x)<1 is not taken into account.
Using the global_assumptions (commented out here) does not give the desired result.

Concretely, how do I evaluate the sum such that the result would be 1/(1-x)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present, the assumptions made by the [assumptions module](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/assumptions/index.html) are not used by the rest of SymPy modules, which makes them less useful than one might hope.

You can sort of fake it by using `.subs` like this:

```
y = sp.Sum(x**k, (k,0,oo)).doit().subs(sp.Abs(x) < 1, True)
```

which returns `1/(-x + 1)`.

I think this is the best one can do at present. Because this is just a literal substitution of True for a condition, rather than a logical inference, it won't work when the assumption doesn't exactly match a condition in Piecewise:

```
y = sp.Sum(x**k, (k,0,oo)).doit().subs(sp.Abs(x) < 1/2, True)   # alas :(
```